# Filtering integers out of python command line arguments

Tags: python

so I wrote a program and I want to pass it either a filename and an integer or just an integer. Whats the best way to determine which argument is the integer? This is what I have:

```
import sys

if len(sys.argv) > 1):
    for e in sys.argv:
        try:
            bio = map(e, int)
        except:
            pass
```

thanks in advance

Comment: is the user allowed to pass in an integer, then a filename?

Comment: no, it will either be a filename then an integer or just an integer

Comment: Could the integer be negative?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could check whether or not the argument is an integer with the string `isdigit()` method:

```
import sys

if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    for e in sys.argv:
        if e.isdigit():
            # all characters in e are digits and there is at least one character in e
        else:
            # it is possibly your filename argument
```

But, I should encourage you to give a chance to the argparse library: http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description = 'A simple description')

parser.add_argument('-f', action = 'store', dest =  'filename', required = False)
parser.add_argument('-n', action = 'store', dest = 'n', required = True, type=int)

arguments = parser.parse_args()

print arguments.n
print arguments.filename
```

Comment: Thanks, I looked into argparse but for my purposes I just needed something simple that would work quickly.

Comment: OK. I just added an argparse example, just in case you change your mind. ;)

Comment: @ptr +1 for argparse -- Although I don't like the `required=True` bit.  Instead, maybe `parser.add_argument('n',...)`.  Then you'd call it as `my_program 1` or `my_program 1 -f filename` or `my_program -f filename 1`.  (instead of `my_program -n 1 -f filename` as you have it)

Comment: Also, you should probably avoid checking sys.argv[0] since that is the name of the program.

Answer (score 2):

```
def isint(val):
    try:
       int(val)
       return True
    except:
       return False

int_args = filter(isint,sys.argv)
not_int_args = set(sys.argv) - set(int_args)
```

Comment: You could do without `isint` if you do `filter(str.isdigit,sys.argv[1:])`

Comment: @Joran Beasley: Try to avoid using a bare except. Catch `ValueError` instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
if len(sys.argv) == 1: #user passed in only one argument. It must be an integer.
    bio = int(sys.argv[0])
elif len(sys.argv) == 2: #user passed in two arguments: filename and integer.
    filename = sys.argv[0]
    bio = int(sys.argv[1])
else: #user didn't pass in the right number of arguments
    raise Exception("Expected one or two arguments")
```